# Using two arrays to create registry keys/values

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell

Trying to automate our font installation process for new PCs.

To install fonts, Windows adds the .ttf, .otf, etc. file to C:\Windows\Fonts and then creates a corresponding registry key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts. A typical registry key would look like this:

Arial (TrueType) | Arial.ttf

To automate this, I've made two arrays using Get-ChildItem:

```
$names = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\corp\install\fonts" | Select-Object name | Out-String | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "----","" ` -Replace "Name","" ` -Replace ".otf","" ` -Replace ".ttf","" } | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\corp\install\fonts" | Select-Object name | Out-String | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "----","" ` -Replace "Name","" } | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
```

Each $name in $names will be the name of the registry key, and each $file in $files will be the data for that registry key.

How would I go about doing this? I've attempted to use hash tables, PSObjects, nested ForEach loops, all to no avail. I have had difficulty finding anything on here and elsewhere that matches this situation exactly.

Error checking is not really necessary since there will always be a corresponding value.

REVISED FINAL SOLUTION:

```
Write-Host "Installing corporate fonts..."
Copy-Item -Path "C:\corp\install\fonts\*" -Destination "C:\Windows\Fonts" -Force -Recurse

$fontList = @()

$fonts = Get-ChildItem "C:\corp\install\fonts" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

ForEach ( $font in $fonts ) {

    $fontList += [PSCustomObject] @{ 
        Name = $font -Replace ".otf","" ` -Replace ".ttf",""
        File = $font
    } |

    ForEach-Object {
        New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" -Name $_.Name -Value $_.File
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit I don't fully understand your question so forgive me if this response is way off base, but it this what you're looking for? A table with both pieces of data in one?

```
Function CreateVariables {

    $namevariables = @()

    $filenames = ( Get-ChildItem "C:\corp\install\fonts" ).name 

    Foreach ( $name in $filenames ){

        $namevariables += [PSCustomObject] @{ 
            Name = $name -Replace "----","" ` -Replace "Name","" ` -Replace ".otf","" ` -Replace ".ttf","" 
            File = $name -Replace "----","" ` -Replace "Name",""
        }
    }

    Return $namevariables
}

CreateVariables
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I realized a bit ago that stripping the arrays and converting to strings was not what I wanted to do, as it makes more work. I appreciate your help, will update the original post with the final solution!

Answer (score 0):

Piping both name and value to set-itemproperty seem impossible.  Foreach-object seems the way to go.

```
$path = 'hklm:\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\fonts' 

[pscustomobject]@{name='a name';value='a value'} | 
  foreach { set-itemproperty $path $_.name $_.value -whatif }

What if: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\fonts Property: a name".
```

You may prefer using this vbscript-like method to install fonts:

https://www.mondaiji.com/blog/other/it/10247-windows-install-fonts-via-command-line